# Adding Tabs to Sencha app in code leaves them disabled/inactive

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am currently learning the Sencha framework and Ext, so please bear with me if this is an obvious noob problem.

If I add the constructor for my tabpanel inside the constructor of the application, the tabs work fine and I can switch between the panels.  If I try to create the tabpanel separately and then add it to the application, the components get added to the DOM, but the tabs do not appear to be enabled and do not work.

I cannot see anything wrong in the DOM using Chromes dev tools, and comparing a working version against a not working version they look identical to me.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or why the following code from an app.js does not function:

```
var panelLowerTabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
flex: 1,
xtype: 'tabpanel',
items: [
        {
            title: 'TAB ONE',
            html: 'First',
            cls: 'card1'
        },
        {
            title: 'TAB TWO',
            html: 'Second',
            cls: 'card1'
        }
        ]
});

Ext.application({
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    tabletStartupScreen: 'images/tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'images/phone_startup.png',

    requires: [
        'Ext.Container',
        'Ext.tab.Panel'
    ],

launch: function () {
    var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [{}]
        });

    container.add(panelLowerTabs);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, I was trying to instantiate the TabPanel object before the application  had launched, and hence before 'requires' had loaded the TabPanel details.

Reordering the code, to create the TabPanel object just before adding it to the container fixes the problem.

```
Ext.application({
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    tabletStartupScreen: 'images/tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'images/phone_startup.png',

    //next we require any components we are using in our application.
    requires: [
    'Ext.Container',
    'Ext.tab.Panel'
],

    launch: function () {
        var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [{}]
        });

        var panelLowerTabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'TAB ONE',
                    html: 'First',
                    cls: 'card1'
                },
                {
                    title: 'TAB TWO',
                    html: 'Second',
                    cls: 'card1'
                }
                ]
        });
        container.add(panelLowerTabs);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, you should always create instances within the application launch method, or your controller when using the MVC architecture. I also recommend you to always use `Ext.create()` instead of the new keyword, as it means it takes advantage of the dynamic loading capabilities of the class system. More information about that available [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/class_system) and [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/building).